# sshuttle on a DD-WRT / OpenWRT Router

Tags: router, dd-wrt, ssh-tunnel, openwrt, sshuttle

Has anybody had any success installing and running sshuttle on a wireless router? My intent is to have all traffic from all devices (computer, tablet, gaming system, etc.) that connect to the router encrypted through the ssh tunnel created by sshuttle running on a router.