# How to use sshuttle on a router running openwrt?

Tags: vpn, tunnel, forwarding, openwrt, sshuttle

I'm using a [TP-Link TL-WR1043ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR1043ND) router running [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) and [Gargoyle](http://www.gargoyle-router.com/). I'd like to forward all traffic from my local network (served by the router) to a remote server transparently. Essentially as a socks proxy would work, just without the need to configure the connected client machines for proxy.

I've read that [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/tree/master) is the way to go for this kind of requirement. After much fiddling, I finally managed to satisfy all prerequisites, and I can start sshuttle without any error messages, like this:

```
./sshuttle --dns -vvr XXXXXX@YY.YY.YY.YY 0/0
```

Where XXXXXX is my username at a remote server YY.YY.YY.YY
sshuttle seems to initialize just fine, no error messages, adds all necessary rules to iptables, yet after the local proxy is established, I'm unable to connect **anywhere** from my local network. This is sshuttle's output:

```
Starting sshuttle proxy.
Binding: 12300
Listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
DNS listening on ('127.0.0.1', 12300).
firewall manager ready.
c : connecting to server...
c : executing: ['ssh', 'XXXXXX@YY.YY.YY.YY', '--', 'P=python2; $P -V 2>/dev/null || P=python; exec "$P" -c \'import sys; skip_imports=1; verbosity=2; exec compile(sys.stdin.read(764), "assembler.py", "exec")\'']
c :  > channel=0 cmd=PING len=7 (fullness=0)
WARNING: Ignoring unknown argument '--'
XXXXXX@YY.YY.YY.YY's password:
server: assembling 'cmdline_options.py' (29 bytes)
server: assembling 'helpers.py' (914 bytes)
server: assembling 'ssubprocess.py' (13668 bytes)
server: assembling 'ssnet.py' (5446 bytes)
server: assembling 'hostwatch.py' (2270 bytes)
server: assembling 'server.py' (2370 bytes)
 s: latency control setting = True
 s: available routes:
 s:   69.64.32.0/22
 s:  > channel=0 cmd=PING len=7 (fullness=0)
c : connected.
Connected.
c : Waiting: 3 r=[3, 5, 9] w=[9] x=[] (fullness=7/0)
c :   Ready: 3 r=[] w=[9] x=[]
c : mux wrote: 15/15
c : Waiting: 3 r=[3, 5, 9] w=[] x=[] (fullness=7/0)
 s:  > channel=0 cmd=ROUTES len=14 (fullness=7)
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[5] x=[] (fullness=21/0)
 s:   Ready: 1 r=[] w=[5] x=[]
 s: mux wrote: 15/15
 s: mux wrote: 22/22
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[] (fullness=21/0)
c :   Ready: 3 r=[9] w=[] x=[]
c : <  channel=0 cmd=PING len=7
c :  > channel=0 cmd=PONG len=7 (fullness=7)
c : <  channel=0 cmd=ROUTES len=14
firewall manager: starting transproxy.
 s:   Ready: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[]
 s: <  channel=0 cmd=PING len=7
 s:  > channel=0 cmd=PONG len=7 (fullness=21)
 s: mux wrote: 15/15
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[] (fullness=28/0)
>> iptables -t nat -N sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -F sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1 -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j RETURN --dest 127.0.0.0/8 -p tcp
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --to-ports 12300 -m ttl ! --ttl 42
>> iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp --dport 53 --to-ports 12300 -m ttl ! --ttl 42
c : mux wrote: 15/15
c : <  channel=0 cmd=PONG len=7
c : received PING response
c : Waiting: 3 r=[3, 5, 9] w=[] x=[] (fullness=0/0)
 s:   Ready: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[]
 s: <  channel=0 cmd=PONG len=7
 s: received PING response
 s: Waiting: 1 r=[4] w=[] x=[] (fullness=0/0)
```

I have no idea how to even start debugging this issue. If I stop sshuttle, it will remove the iptables rules and network connections will work again:

```
firewall manager: undoing changes.
>> iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -j sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -F sshuttle-12300
>> iptables -t nat -X sshuttle-12300
c :
c : Keyboard interrupt: exiting.
```

Has anyone managed to set up a working sshuttle instance on openwrt? Or is there any other way to achieve what I need here (transparent proxy on an openwrt router)?

Related and unanswered question: [sshuttle on a DD-WRT / OpenWRT Router](https://superuser.com/questions/576519/sshuttle-on-a-dd-wrt-openwrt-router)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Luckily I got an answer at the [sshuttle google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sshuttle/ZIxlBnkjEqg) from the author of sshuttle. He wrote:

> You might need to add '-l 0.0.0.0' (that's a lowercase L) in order to 
>   tell sshuttle to listen for connections from other than localhost (the
>   router itself).  For security reasons, sshuttle won't route other 
>   people's traffic by default.

And it works perfectly! Use:

> ./sshuttle -l 0.0.0.0 --dns -vvr XXXXXX@YY.YY.YY.YY 0/0

Comment: My use case is running sshuttle on the host for forwarding traffic of Docker containers while they are building, and this works great.

Answer (score 5):

A few things that tripped me up:

From stock OpenWRT 12.09 AA, you have to install these packages:

1. `python` (with dependencies, consumes 3-4 MB of flash)
2. `iptables-mod-nat-extra`
3. `iptables-mod-ipopt`

Then, to SSH into the remote server using an SSH key, you have to create a Dropbear-format key:

```
dropbearkey -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And finally, provide the key location on the `sshuttle` command line:

```
./sshuttle -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa" -l 0.0.0.0 -r xxxxxx@yy.yy.yy.yy 0/0 -vv --dns
```

Answer (score 0):

On GL-AR300M router which runs OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05 the procedure seems to be slightly different than what @trapezoid described. Maybe it's not quite stock OpenWRT (I didn't reinstall after buying), or it's just the passage of time.

I installed the packages they named, i.e. `python iptables-mod-nat-extra iptables-mod-ipopt`.

For ssh key based login to work, I didn't need to generate a special ssh key, my usual one was enough, but the `autorized_keys` needed to be moved to `/etc/dropbear/` (that is, `ssh-copy-id` didn't put it in the right directory).